# Wordpress dashboard not showing any thing except profile

Tags: html, wordpress, windows, web

Can anybody help??? The wordPress[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58D13.jpg) dashboard not showing anything except the profile. Please look at the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the logged in user is a subscriber only? If that is your only account, you will need to edit the user permissions directly via the database. If you have another admin user, login as them and check the user rights.